# Regex Comparison in Shell Script

Tags: xcode, bash, shell

In Xcode 8 I have a Run Script that is comparing a string to a regex:

```
if [ "$MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" =~ ".+(Debug)" ]
then
RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Debug
elif [ "$MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" =~ ".+(Test)" ]
then
RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Production
elif [ "$MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" =~ ".+(ProductionTest)" ]
then
RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Test
else
RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Store
fi
```

The variable `$MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` will be one of the following:

```
com.cnt.Filer
com.cnt.Filer.ProductionTest
com.cnt.Filer.Debug
com.cnt.Filer.Test
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
line 4: [: =~: binary operator expected
line 7: [: =~: binary operator expected
line 10: [: =~: binary operator expected
```

In the full script lines 4, 7 and 10 are the then statements.

Does anyone know how I can successfully compare my variable to the regex?

Comment: The single `[` is the old shell built-in, also known as `test`.  It is not used for text pattern matching (neither RE nor globbing),  only limited filename expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should be using `[[ string =~ regex ]]` for regex in BASH
2. Don't quote regex
3. Looks like you don't even need regex, you can just do string comparison using `==`

Your script can be this:

```
if [[ $MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER == *Debug* ]]; then
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Debug
elif [[ $MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER == *Test* ]]; then
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Production
elif [[ $MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER == *ProductionTest* ]]; then
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Test
else
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Store
fi
```

**PS:** You may also consider using `case`

```
case "$MOBILE_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER" in
*Debug*)
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Debug
   ;;
*Test*)
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Production
   ;;
*ProductionTest*)
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Test
   ;;
*)
   RESOURCE_PATH=${SRCROOT}/Resources/Clients/Cnt/Files/Store
   ;;
esac
```